# Do Trespassing and No trespassing mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning

The meanings  of **Exit** and **NO Exi**t or **Entry** and **NO** **Entry** are naturally opposite.

When I see an **[Entry]** sign, it means '**enter here'**.

When I see a **[No Entry]** sign, it means **'do not enter**'.

In this respect, considering the definition of trespassing, what would 
a [No trespassing] sign mean? Could it mean *free to enter? (No - No entry without permission?)

> *No* *Entry* means the contrary of *Entry*. *No Trespassing* shall therefore
>   means the contrary of *Trespassing*? How could appearance defy logic?
>
> **Are we putting the car before the horse? In order to trespass, someone first needs to enter without permission. If there already were a no
>   trespassing sign before someone had even been entering, could the absence
>   of trespassing be interpreted as a green light?**

Answer (score 2):

> [Trespass](http://www.dictionary.com/): to enter the owner's land or property without permission.
>
> No Trespassing: Do not enter the owner's land or property without permission.

They are contradictory as **trespassing** is essentially meaning *go on a land that isn't yours without your permission*, while **no trespassing** means *DON'T go on that land that isn't yours*

Comment: So that their ''contradictory meanings'' of which you speak be reflected without ''hidden nuances'', you need to add " without your permission '' at the end of BOTH definitions. The result would be exactly relevant to the point I am trying to make.

Comment: What is the point you are trying to make. I don't understand what you are trying to say now

Answer (score 0):

A "No Trespassing" sign means exactly what it suggests: If to trespass is to enter without permission, no trespassing means **Do not enter without permission**.

I don't think I've ever seen a sign encouraging trespassing as it wouldn't make sense - to encourage it would be to give permission, so it would no longer be trespassing!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72373/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-kolya-mansley-do-trespassing-and-no-trespassing-mean).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a sign saying "Enter" gives permission to enter. You are also correct that "trespass" means "enter without permission. Thus a sign that said "Trespassing" would be self-contradictory because it would be giving permission to enter without permission.

You are also correct that a sign saying "No Exit" denies permission to exit. So a sign saying "No Trespassing" denies permission to enter without permission. It may be redundant, but it is not contradictory. It means "Keep Out."

Comment: Yes. I am asking what would be the definition of NO trespass.

Comment: If trespassing meant 'entry without permission is not allowed', what would 'no' trespassing entail but the contrary?

Comment: But that's the thing, trespassing is the **act of entering without permission**, it's **No Trespassing** that states it's not allowed.

Comment: if no trespassing states it's not allowed, then what does trespassing state?

Comment: @Specialist  you're needlessly confusing the subject.  *To trespass* has a precisely defined definition that is clearly different from *to enter*.  There is no hidden nuance.

Comment: _If trespassing meant 'entry without permission is not allowed'_ - oops! That's where your logic is off. Trespassing simply means "entering without permission"; therefore, NO TRESPASSING means "no entering without permission.

Comment: @ Andrew To 'needlessly confused the subject' is a harsh and quite severe observation.

Comment: @ J.R "That's where your logic is off' is unkind. Whenever you don't agree, debate your ideas instead. To be even, telling me I'm off, or I don't make sense, is still the result of your own understanding.

Comment: @Specialist - You seemed confused. And I thought you were here to learn – that’s what this community is about. If you are going to interpret earnest efforts to help you understand as “unkind,” maybe you should find another place to ask your questions.

Comment: @ J.R-  By way of  ''If you thought I was here to learn'', were you there teaching?